# Deployment Error caused by Entity (Ecommerce)

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans, deployment, controller

I'm really stuck here and I'd love to get some help right about now.
Everytime I try to deploy, it keeps saying that it failed.

EDIT:
Okay so I've realized that the main issue seems to be:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7154] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The attribute [productCollection] in entity class [class entity.Category] has a mappedBy value of [category] which does not exist in its owning entity class [class entity.Product]. If the owning entity class is a @MappedSuperclass, this is invalid, and your attribute should reference the correct subclass.
```

The entity classes are as follows:

Category.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Category.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Category c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Category.findById", query = "SELECT c FROM Category c WHERE c.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Category.findByName", query = "SELECT c FROM Category c WHERE c.name = :name")})
public class Category implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Short id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "category")
    private Collection<Product> productCollection;

    public Category() {
    }

    public Category(Short id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Category(Short id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Short getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Short id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Collection<Product> getProductCollection() {
        return productCollection;
    }

    public void setProductCollection(Collection<Product> productCollection) {
        this.productCollection = productCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Category)) {
            return false;
        }
        Category other = (Category) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entity.Category[id=" + id + "]";
    }

}
```

Product.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findById", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByName", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByPrice", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.price = :price"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByDescription", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.description = :description"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByLastUpdate", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.lastUpdate = :lastUpdate")})
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "price")
    private BigDecimal price;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "last_update")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastUpdate;
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Category categoryId;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "product")
    private Collection<OrderedProduct> orderedProductCollection;

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Product(Integer id, String name, BigDecimal price, Date lastUpdate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdate() {
        return lastUpdate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdate(Date lastUpdate) {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }

    public Category getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(Category categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<OrderedProduct> getOrderedProductCollection() {
        return orderedProductCollection;
    }

    public void setOrderedProductCollection(Collection<OrderedProduct> orderedProductCollection) {
        this.orderedProductCollection = orderedProductCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Product)) {
            return false;
        }
        Product other = (Product) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entity.Product[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

Please help me as soon as possible.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution.

All i had to do was change:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "category")
```

to

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "categoryId")
```

Because in my Product.java, the category is mentioned as:

```
public Category getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }
```